# vk api message.send отправляем ссылку

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Вообщем разрабатываю робота для вк, и возникла необходимость отправить ссылку.
В телеграмме, чтобы отправить ссылку надо включить `parse_mode`, но для вконтакте я ничего подобного не нащел, а если просто вставить ссылку то он и отправит её как строку. Для отправки использую расширение `LukasAndreano/VKBotAPI` Нужна помощь, как отправить ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Увы, силами api этого сделать нельзя.

> Через API на данный момент не получится отправить сниппет (превью) ссылки в сообщении, это можно сделать только в полной версии сайта. Посредством API в сообщении можно отправить только саму ссылку методом [messages.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send).

Источник: [vk.com/faq11772](https://vk.com/faq11772)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, благодарю за дельное замечание. Постарался исправить ответ в соответсвии с ним.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание! Редкий новый участник так поступит. Он будет говорить: "Иди на фиг, нормальный ответ" ;)